# Getting Textmate to create PHP autoload class name from filepath

Tags: php, textmate, autoload, code-snippets

What I would like is a snippet that when executed, grabs the TM_FILEPATH output
Explodes it on the slash /
Then split out each part as a placeholder containing that part and an underscore (apart from the last part (the filename))
For Example:
for a file in directory path
/Path/To/Original/file
we would get

```
class ${1:Path_}${2:To_}${3:Original_}${4:File} {
    // code here
}
```

Then I can step through and remove the parts I don't want
ending with a className that fits the standard PHP autoloader

Does this sound possible?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to add this final result as an answer to enable code display.
Just make sure you set 'output as snippet'

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$path = $_ENV['TM_FILEPATH'];
$path = trim($path, '/');
$path = trim($path, '.php');
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$lastPart = end($parts);
echo 'class ';
foreach ($parts as $id => $part) {
    // textmate placeholders start at 1
    $id = $id+1;
    if ($lastPart == $part) {
        echo '${'.$id.':'.$part.'}';
    } else {
        echo '${'.$id.':'.$part.'_}';
    }
}
?>
```